# Предлагаю объединить метки “частица-не” и “не”

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Предлагаю объединить метки [частица-не](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5) и [не](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5). У метки [не](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5) нет описания. Так пусть метка [частица-не](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5) будет главной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь! Метки объединены, а синоним – создан :)